# errors went out after saving object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I add errors in object and save it. I lost those errors which I added.
Ex :

```
@student.errors.add(:base,"error added " )

@student.save

@student.errors.size ---> 0
```

Please eneyone can say why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to save the object after adding the error? The `errors` are either added through model validations or we add them through some custom logic. The object is not saved in both cases. If you save the object, you would lose the errors.

Comment: So we can save object even if it have errors, right? But ideally when object have errors it should not save then why I am able to save object?

Comment: Suppose you are saving/updating an object and the model validations add some `errors`, the object will not be saved. But, if you are adding any error manually and then saving the object, it will be saved without any issues and the error will be lost.